# How to run Scala code in Airflow using Scala Operator

Tags: scala, airflow

I just wrote a recovery process to Aerospike and its looks like it fits great to Airflow, I'm looking for some Airflow Operator to Scala.

Current Implementation:

```
 // Register UDF for LUT
  aerospikeService.registerUDFs(
    """
      |function getLUT(r)
      |    return record.last_update_time(r)
      |end
      |""".stripMargin
  )

  // Pause Connectors
  k8sService.pauseConnectors()

  // Get Connectors, Current Offsets and LUTs
  val connectors = k8sService.getConnectors()
  val originalState = kafkaService.getCurrentState()
  val startTime = aerospikeService.calculateCurrentLUTs()

  // Delete Connectors
  k8sService.deleteConnectors()
  kafkaService.resetOffsets(originalState)

  // Recreate Connectors
  k8sService.createConnectors(connectors)

  // Wait until Offset Reached
  kafkaService.waitTillOriginalOffsetsReached(originalState)

  // Truncate
  aerospikeService.truncate(startTime, durableDelete)

  // Cleanup
  aerospikeService.cleanup()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no "ScalaOperator" in Airflow to run Scala code. Python is not a JVM language, so you'll need to build a jar file, which can be executed from another process. For example, using a BashOperator in Airflow:

```py
scala_task = BashOperator(
    task_id="scala_task",
    dag=dag,
    bash_command="java -jar myjar.jar",
)
```

Another popular solution is to build your code into a Docker container and start that on a Kubernetes cluster using the KubernetesPodOperator.

Note that the BashOperator (1) requires the JVM to exist on the Airflow worker nodes, and (2) if triggered with the BashOperator, the process will run on the worker nodes, so ensure there are enough resources to handle that. If not, "outsource" the heavy processing elsewhere, e.g. a K8S or Spark cluster.

Comment: I miss jump-to-definition